# SQL Запрос с UUID()

Tags: php, html, sql, smarty

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла проблема с кода не `INSERT`-ся функция:

```
function bookingInsert($hotelid, $roomid, $dtarrive, $dtdepart, $userid, $price, $status){
$cn = dbConnect();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbooking(hotelid, roomid, dtarrive, dtdepart, userid, bookingcode, price, status) VALUES ('".$hotelid."',".$roomid.",".$dtarrive.", '".$dtdepart."',".$userid.", UUID() ,".$price.",'".$status.")");
    mysql_close($cn);
}
```

В SQL запрос обрабатывается но с формы не идет.
Код в INDEX:

```
bookingInsert($_POST["hotelid"], $_POST["roomid"], $_POST["dtarrive"], $_POST["dtdepart"], $_POST["userid"], $_POST["price"], $_POST["status"]);
```

Сама форма: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предполагаю что проблема с UUID()

Comment: Видимо, одинарных кавычек не хватает.

Comment: UUID ведь не цифровое.

Comment: Работает ли запрос если вместо UUID использовать какую-нибудь строку? И еще  в функции bookingInsert выведите сформированный запрос перед mysql_query и приведите здесь.

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbooking(hotelid, roomid, dtarrive, dtdepart, userid, price, status) VALUES ('".$hotelid."','".$roomid."',".$dtarrive.", ".$dtdepart.",'".$userid."','".$price."','".$status."')");
Убрал полностью, пробовал в bookingcode просто поставить значение, не инсертится. Значит проблема в INDEX-е или форме, перепроверил пока не нашел проблему

Comment: ",'".$status.")" - здесь, по крайней мере, нет закрывающей кавычки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой вариант подошел `mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbooking(hotelid, roomid, dtarrive, dtdepart, userid, bookingcode, price, status) VALUES (".$hotelid.",".$roomid.",'".$dtarrive."', '".$dtdepart."',".$userid.", UUID(), ".$price.",".$status.")");`
Ограничение UUID идет в таблице по кол-ву символов, чтобы пользователю было удобно посмотреть запомнить или выписать код